# Mongoose & MongoDB: Cast Error when adding sub schema element to array of parent schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a practice project and I'm getting an error I haven't been able to solve. In my backend, I have a blog controller and a blog model as well, as a comment model and a comment controller. When I try to add a comment I get the following error message:

```
CastError: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "[{"commentText":"Cool","authorName":"David"}]" (type string) at path "comments.0"
    at model.Query.exec (/Users/david/Documents/Coding/codingChallenge/react-blog-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4498:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (/Users/david/Documents/Coding/codingChallenge/react-blog-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4592:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

In my controller, I'm hitting the addComment Request where I select the specific BlogPost document, and then add a comment to the comment array.

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import BaseController from '../baseController';
import { BlogPostSchema } from '../../repository/blogPost';

export default class BlogPostController extends BaseController {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  public async test(req: Request, res: Response) {
    res.status(200).send('test worked');
  }

  public async addComment(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const newComment = req.body;
    const updatedBlogPost = await BlogPostSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      { $push: { comments: newComment } },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.status(200).send(updatedBlogPost);
  }
}
```

That request uses the Blog model/schema

```
import {
  createSchema,
  ExtractDoc,
  ExtractProps,
  Type,
  typedModel
} from 'ts-mongoose';
import { commentSchema } from './comment';

export const blogPostSchema = createSchema(
  {
    authorName: Type.string({ trim: true }),
    blogText: Type.string({ trim: true }),
    category: Type.string({
      default: '',
      trim: true,
      enum: ['gaming', 'lifestyle', 'cooking', 'baking']
    }),
    comments: Type.array().of(
      Type.ref(Type.objectId()).to('comment', commentSchema)
    )
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true
  }
);

export const BlogPostSchema = typedModel('blogPost', blogPostSchema);
export type BlogPost = ExtractProps<typeof blogPostSchema>;
export type BlogPostDoc = ExtractDoc<typeof blogPostSchema>;
```

The BlogPostSchema then uses the Comment Schema

```
import {
  createSchema,
  ExtractDoc,
  ExtractProps,
  Type,
  typedModel
} from 'ts-mongoose';

export const commentSchema = createSchema(
  {
    commentText: Type.string({ trim: true }),
    authorName: Type.string({ trim: true })
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true
  }
);

export const CommentModel = typedModel('comment', commentSchema);
export type Comment = ExtractProps<typeof commentSchema>;
export type CommentDoc = ExtractDoc<typeof commentSchema>;
```

What should be my next steps in problem solving, or a potential solution to this problem?

edit: I have also tried this for the addComment request, and it has not worked either.

```
public async addComment(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const newComment = await BlogPostSchema.create(req.body);
    const updatedBlogPost = await BlogPostSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      { $push: { comments: newComment } },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.status(200).send(updatedBlogPost);
  }
```